# Mongodb Group and Count Where Column is Status

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a mongo query to group all of my records by status. I then want to get a count per status. I have managed to do this with a `$group` query but now I would like to take it a step further and make the property name reflect the status and the value equal the count. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Edit:This is different from the question that was marked as a duplicate
I still need to group it by status and I cant group by status and get a sum of status in the same group. The duplicate questions is grouping by name and getting a sum of logs based on title which is a sum of an embedded document not a sum off all documents. Status is not embedded it is a singluar property per document.

Mongo Query:

```
db.getCollection('winapplications').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'WINNbr': { '$exists': true, '$ne': '' } } },
    { $match: {"Status":{"$ne":"Approved"}}},
    { $match: {"Status":{"$ne":""}}},
    { $match: {"Status":{"$ne":null}}},
    {
        $group: {
           _id: "$Status",
            count:{$sum:1}
        } 
    }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : "Hold",
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Pending",
    "count" : 235.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Not Approved",
    "count" : 4199.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Active",
    "count" : 1923.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Closed",
    "count" : 20189.0
}
```

What I would like:

```
{
    "Hold" : 1
    "Pending" : 235
    "Not Approved" : 4199
    "Active" : 1923
    "Closed" : 20189,
}
```

The result I get when I do what the duplicate question says is not the result I am asking for:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Hold",
    "Active" : 0.0,
    "Closed" : 0.0,
    "Pending" : 0.0,
    "Hold" : 1.0,
    "Not Approved" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Pending",
    "Active" : 0.0,
    "Closed" : 0.0,
    "Pending" : 235.0,
    "Hold" : 0.0,
    "Not Approved" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Not Approved",
    "Active" : 0.0,
    "Closed" : 0.0,
    "Pending" : 0.0,
    "Hold" : 0.0,
    "Not Approved" : 4199.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Active",
    "Active" : 1923.0,
    "Closed" : 0.0,
    "Pending" : 0.0,
    "Hold" : 0.0,
    "Not Approved" : 0.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "Closed",
    "Active" : 0.0,
    "Closed" : 20189.0,
    "Pending" : 0.0,
    "Hold" : 0.0,
    "Not Approved" : 0.0
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem. To get the result that I was wanting, not the one in the duplicate you have to project a supplementary property like Type: {$literal: "All"} and then group by Type. This will return the correct result and is the answer to this question which is still different from the duplicate.

Comment: Can this please be reopened so I can provide an answer to it in case someone else needs help with this.